# Linux command to subsample from stdin

Tags: linux, stdin, random

I want to randomly retain a fraction (say 0.001) of all the lines streaming in through stdin. Is there a linux command that does that?

I can always write a python script to generate a uniform random number and based on whether it is <= 0.001 retain the line. But I want to avoid writing my own script and was looking for a native command in linux.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to write your own...

Comment: Really? This seems like a case useful enough to warrant a native linux command. Even a nasty expression involving awk/sed/etc would do.

Comment: You're right, may be `shuf` from coreutils can do the trick. It can shuffle the lines and you can ask for at most `n` entries...

Comment: `shuf` and `sort` might not work because these commands need to look at the entire file (or entire set of lines). In my case, stdin will have too many lines to fit in memory. I want the ability to make a decision to drop or retain for each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it native enough?

```
cat input | awk 'rand() <= 0.001'
```

EDIT: To make it return different set of lines each second:

```
cat input | awk 'BEGIN{srand();} rand() <= 0.001'
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.

Comment: How do I make it random? Different runs give me the same set of lines.

Comment: You need to initialize random number generator. See my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, that prints nothing. I'll tweak around `srand`. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. @gudok's edit works perfectly. I forgot to change `0.001` to `0.1` while testing on a file with 100 lines and hence was ending up with 0 lines :)

Comment: BTW, since this is relevant. We can probably have truly random numbers soon: https://threatpost.com/academics-make-theoretical-breakthrough-in-random-number-generation/118150/

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux distributions also include a distribution of the [BSD games](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/BSD_games) (package `bsdgames` on Debian-based distributions and `bsd-games` on Redhat-based distributions).  With that package installed, you can simply use the `random` filter, which does exactly what you want:

```
cat input | random 100
```

will print every 100th line on average.

Comment: This would have been perfect if *all* linux distributions had this command. Hence not marking as the accepted answer, but thanks for bringing this to notice.